# Anime about a boy detective who does his job, not to help people, but for the money

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find an anime which has a boy detective or something similar, but he does his job not to help people but for the money. He has a girl assistant that controls a flying robot.

The boy has dark brown hair, hazel eyes and a uniform, kind of light brown, with a cap which has a symbol his brother gave to him.

There are comedy scenes where he and his assistant go in a weaponry shop to buy guns but they always get a discount. Also the end was about his assistant the girl, being a slave for experiments.

**Can someone help me remember the name of it?**

Comment: Trickster? Mnemosyne  ? Conan?

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this and did you watch it on TV or online? If you watched it on TV, do you recall which channel or channels might you have seen it on?

Answer (score 2):

**Gunjou no Magmell**

[image]

Synopsis:

> A new era of exploration begins with the sudden appearance of a new continent known as Magmell. Magmell's vast trove of never-before-seen natural resources spurs on the exploration of its vast landscape. However, the unknown is not always docile. In order to sustain the expeditions, people known as "anglers" specialize in dealing with Magmell's dangerous wildlife. One such angler is the highly-skilled and experienced Inyou, who performs search and rescue operations for clients with the help of his assistant, Zero.
> Source: https://myanimelist.net/anime/37806/Gunjou_no_Magmell

The main character Inyou wears a uniform and fits your description. His assistent Zero helps him on his missions by being his eyes and ears by controlling some kind of drone. Didn't watch all of it, so don't know the end.

Feel free to edit my answer if it lacks information.